# Using Case with no column result

Tags: database-design, case

I made this solution but it continues not returning any value If the user not exists.

```
select
    case when TypeId = 1 then 1 
         when TypeId = 0 then 2
         when count(1) < 1 then 3
         end 
    from Type 
    where mail = 'name@test.com'
    group by Type
```

Comment: The WHERE clause dictates how many rows are returned. Can't your application handle the case where no rows are returned? Count can't be anything but 0 in that case, right?

Comment: Which DBMS is this for?

Answer (score 1):

Application would be much better place to deal with such cases as **Aaron Bertrand** said but you can do it with SQL as well .

```
select
    case when TypeId = 1 then 1 
         when TypeId = 0 then 2
         end 
    from Type 
    where mail = 'name@test.com'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 
FROM DUAL 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Type WHERE mail = 'name@test.com')
```

**Depends on RDMS you're using you may or may not need specify "FROM DUAL".